# Limit records in sales order grid

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order

My sales order table has total 17000 records. Need to select and show only last 300 records in sales order grid.
I have tried the below code, but it's not working

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
    $collection->getSelect()->limit(300);
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

Comment: This gets controlled through the "View 20 per page" dropdown above the grid - you can't do it in the `_prepareCollection` method

Comment: Magento showing 20 orders by default in sales grid and you can change it to max 200 from drop-down.  Do you want to set 300 by default on the page ?

Comment: Ok. Is there any option to select only 300 records? I don't want the 17000 records

Comment: @AkhileshPatel  No. In top of the sales order grid, total recotds count shown as 170000. I selected "View 20 per page" option and there are total  856 pages

Comment: I want to show it as 300 records as total count. Please check my code i limited the records

Comment: Does this speed up order grid loading time?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working code:

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $this->setDefaultLimit(200);
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
    $collection->getSelect()->limit(300);
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

Since the max limit is 200, you have to set the default limit to 200 and select query limit to 300. This will give you two grid pages.

Comment: Which file is being changed here?